# 419 Page Expired

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Trato de almacenar la información de un formulario por medio de `POST` y me devuelve un mensaje :

> 419 Page Expired

Lo cual no sucede cuando utilizo `GET`.

Formulario HTML:

```
<form action="{{url('guardar')}}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label>Nombre:</label><input type="text" name="nombre"><br>
<label>Apellido:</label><input type="text" name="apellido"><br>
<label>Cedula:</label><input type="text" name="cedula"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar Datos" name="">
</form>
```

Rutas :

```
use proyecto\personas;

Route::get('formulario', function () {

   return view('usuarios');

});



Route::post("guardar","Persona@store");
```

Controlador Persona :

```
     public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $game = new personas;
        $game->nombre = $request->get('nombre');
        $game->apellido = $request->get('apellido');
        $game->cedula = $request->get('cedula');
        $game->save();
        return "Guardado existoso";
    }
```

Modelo personas:

```
<?php

namespace proyecto;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class personas extends Model
{
    protected $table='persona';

    protected $fillable=[
    'nombre','apellido','cedula',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
<form action="algunaRuta" method="POST">

    @csrf
```

Lo anterior genera un token único por petición de modo que Laravel conozca y confié en él.

Considera que:

- Si por alguna razón usas una versión igual o inferior a [Laravel 5.5](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-introduction) entonces deberás manejar esta propuesta con esta sintaxis:

  ```
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  ```
- En caso contrario, es decir Laravel 5.6 o superior entonces puedes apoyarte de la sintaxis ya mencionada

**Referencias**

- Puedes revisar este [enlace](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf) para conocer más al respecto
- [token csrf](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/csrf#csrf-introduction)

Comment: follow up: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery , https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)

Comment: Falta contexto para que la gente entienda donde va el @csrf, y si va entre {{ }} o no...

Comment: @JuliSmz listo ahi tienes lo que mencionas, indicando como usarlo y en que versiones se puede o no aplicar

Comment: Gracias por editarlo, ahora la respuesta es completa y no es necesaria una segunda. Eliminada, saludos!