# Metodo post de laravel da error 419

Tags: laravel, mvc, eloquent

Tengo un problema haciendo un post, por alguna razón no puede hacer POST y da un error 419

Debido a este error, no se envian los datos a la base de datos, no es un error 404 ya que si encuentra una pagina, pero no parece saber como mandar los datos

Éste es el controlador que estoy usando, el cual debe salvar la cuenta en la base de datos. Se llama CheckoutController, su función es hacer la compra.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Checkout;

use Redirect;

use Session;

class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    public function postStorage(Request $request){ //Crear el usuario
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'name|required|unique:storages',
            'address' => 'required|min:4',
            'card-name' => 'required|min:4',
            'card-number' => 'required|min:4',
            'card-expiry-month' => 'required|min:4',
            'card-expiry-year' => 'required|min:4',
            'card-cvc' => 'required|min:4',
            'total' => 'required|min:4',
        ]); //Valida

        $checkout=new Checkout([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'address' => $request->input('address'),
            'card-name' => $request->input('card-name'),
            'card-number' => $request->input('card-number'),
            'card-expiry-month' => $request->input('card-expiry-month'),
            'card-expiry-year' => $request->input('card-expiry-year'),
            'card-cvc' => $request->input('card-cvc'),
            'total' => $request->input('total'),
        ]);

        $checkout->save(); //Salva al usuario
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }
}
```

Este es el modelo del Checkout, el cual contiene los siguientes datos

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Checkout extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'address', 'card-name', 'card-number', 
    'card-expiry-month', 'card-expiry-year', 'card-cvc', 'total'];
}
```

Esta es mi ruta en web.php. La cual tiene un metodo de POST

```
Route::post('/checkout', [
    'uses' => 'CheckoutController@postStorage',
    'as'=> 'checkout',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

Esto es lo que contengo en checkout.blade.php. Me gustaria saber porque da un error 419 especificamente

```
@extends('layouts.master') 

@section('title')
 Shopping Cart
@endsection

@section('content')
      <h1>Checkout</h1>
      <h4>Total: ${{ $total }}</h4>

      </div>

<form action="{{ route('checkout') }}" method="post">
<div class="box-body col-xs-12">
<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
                      <label for="nombre">Titular</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="name" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                      <label for="apellido">Direccion</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="address" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                      <label for="ciudad">Nombre de la tarjeta</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="card-name" name="card-name" placeholder="nombre" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                      <label for="institucion">Numero de la tarjeta</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="card-number" name="card-number" placeholder="numero" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                      <label for="institucion">Mes que expira</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="card-expiry-month" name="card-expiry-month" placeholder="mes" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                      <label for="institucion">Año que expira</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="card-expiry-year" name="card-expiry-year" placeholder="año" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                      <label for="institucion">CVC</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="card-cvc" name="card-cvc" placeholder="cvc" >
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-3">
                      <label for="institucion">Total</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="total" name="total" placeholder="${{ $total }}" value="${{ $total }}" disabled>
</div>


<div class="form-group col-xs-12">

</div>

<div class="box-footer col-xs-12 ">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</button>
</div>


</form>

</div>
@endsection
```

Nota: Logre arreglar el problema, pero por alguna razón, no quiere agarrar el valor del "total" que se ve en $total. Dice que es null

Yo traigo el valor que dice total de ProductController, el cual contiene los siguientes datos y posee la siguiente ruta

ProductController, el método de getCheckout se trae el total

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Cart;
use App\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Session;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex(){ //Muestra el index
        $products = Product::all(); //Se trae los productos del modelo
        return view('shop.index', ['products' => $products]);
    }

    public function getAddToCart(Request $request, $id){
        $product = Product::find($id); //Agarra la id del producto
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;  //Determina si ya hay un carrito
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart); //Agarra los datos del carrito viejo
        $cart->add($product, $product->id); //Mete los productos

        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        //dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
        return redirect()->route('product.index');
    }

    public function getReducedByOne($id){
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;  //Determina si ya hay un carrito
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart); //Agarra los datos del carrito viejo
        $cart->reduceByOne($id); //Busca la funcion que esta en el Cart.php
        Session::put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->route('product.shoppingCart');
    }

    public function getRemoveItem($id){
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;  //Determina si ya hay un carrito
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart); //Agarra los datos del carrito viejo
        $cart->removeItem($id); //Busca la funcion que esta en el Cart.php

        if($cart->items > 0){
            Session::put('cart', $cart); //Mantiene el carro si aun hay items 
        }else{
            Session::forget('cart'); //Borra el carro entero
        }
        return redirect()->route('product.shoppingCart');
    }

    public function getCart(){
        if(!Session::has('cart')){ //Agarra y muestra el carro 
            return view('shop.shopping-cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart); 
        return view('shop.shopping-cart', ['products' => $cart->items, 
        'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);
    }

    public function getCheckout(){ //Muestra el checkout
        if(!Session::has('cart')){
            return view('shop.shopping-cart');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $total = $cart->totalPrice;
        return view('shop.checkout', ['total' => $total]);
    }


}
```

Ruta

```
Route::get('/checkout', [
    'uses' => 'ProductController@getCheckout',
    'as'=> 'checkout',
    'middleware' => 'auth'
]);
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [419 Page Expired](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/280430/419-page-expired)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

agrega esto en tu codigo dentro del formulario

`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ @csrf }}" />`

Espero te funcione, comentanos como te fue.

Comment: Yo tengo el mismo problema, pero en mi formulario si tiene la directiva csrf